# Conditional Statement on people in the same city

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a, simplified, table (myPeeps) with 2 columns: city and name

1. If in the same city there is John and Mary I need to only display row for Mary
2. If in the same city there is John, Mary and Steve, I need to only show row for John
3. If in the same city there is John and Steve, show for for Steve

if there is another combination, not stated in the rule above, must show each row

How would I do this? Do I need an extra join? Or do I use a case when?

Comment: What are the rules that you are using?

Comment: the rules as stated above, there are 3 possibilities of what needs to display. Mary John and Steve and the only options.

Comment: Ok, "why" are those the rules? What is the logic behind them? What if Mary and Steve are in the same city? What about just John, or just Steve, or just Mary?

Comment: these are business rules as provided by the application. they are hardcoded values that when in combination with each other, should display properly. if any other combination shows up (which it would not) display all values

Comment: so in all other cases it should do what? Display no rows at all?

Comment: I think the simplification is hiding the real problem here.

Comment: My opinion would be that a CASE WHEN would provide you with the most flexibility for this kind of decision matrix.

Comment: I don't see a way to do this in SQL, but why this won't be solved inside application code? Seems more beneficial

Comment: Richard, Yes, these are the only values that can appear

Comment: But what about Jane? Is she not allowed to use your application because she doesn't have a name you recognise?

Comment: that is right, Jane is now allowed. only the 3 people above can live in my city ;)

Comment: iirc in SQL Server you can use a CTE, so you need to create a set of data that checks for condition and have a count column, reuse this result in further SQL queries. I am not sure if this may help you much

Comment: And what if only Mary?

Comment: thank you, i updated the question. if there is another combination of names, not stated in the rule above, must show each row

Comment: I don't understand why are you asking him for more details like it solves the problem. You got input and output, anything else is unspecified tho irrevelant

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek because the question is over simplified. Without asking those details what does happen with those situations?

Comment: For this data [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3e6417b50014ceaad706dda3e71d49e3) what is the expected result, and "why" (What is in the post doesn't explain why, just the "what").

Answer (score 3):

Using `STRING_AGG`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT city, STRING_AGG(name, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY name)AS people
  FROM tab
  GROUP BY city
)
SELECT *
FROM tab t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM cte c
              WHERE t.city = c.city 
                AND CASE c.people
                       WHEN 'John,Mary' THEN 'Mary'
                       WHEN 'John,Mary,Steve' THEN 'John'
                       WHEN 'John,Steve' THEN 'Steve'
                       ELSE t.name
                    END = t.name)
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e0ab8659a5fc6471852e916af5ee21a3)**

Example:

```
+-----+-----------+-------+
| id  |   city    | name  |
+-----+-----------+-------+
|  1  | Montreal  | John  |
|  2  | Montreal  | Mary  |
|  3  | Berlin    | Mary  |
|  4  | Berlin    | Steve |
|  5  | Berlin    | John  |
|  6  | Tokyo     | Steve |
|  7  | Tokyo     | John  |
|  8  | Moscow    | Mary  |
|  9  | Moscow    | Steve |
+-----+-----------+-------+

-- Output:

+-----+-----------+-------+
| id  |   city    | name  |
+-----+-----------+-------+
|  2  | Montreal  | Mary  |
|  5  | Berlin    | John  |
|  6  | Tokyo     | Steve |
|  8  | Moscow    | Mary  |
|  9  | Moscow    | Steve |
+-----+-----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really weird.  I would count the special values and use logic:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when name = 'John' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by city) as has_john,
             sum(case when name = 'Mary' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by city) as has_mary,
             sum(case when name = 'Steve' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by city) as has_steve,
             sum(case when name not in ('John', 'Mary', 'Steve') then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by city) as has_others
      from t
     ) t
where (name = 'Mary' and has_john = 1 and has_mary = 1 and has_steve = 0 and has_others = 0) or
      (name = 'John' and has_john = 1 and has_mary = 1 and has_steve = 1 and has_others = 0) or
      (name = 'Steve' and has_john = 1 and has_mary = 0 and has_steve = 1 and has_others = 0) or
      (not (has_john = 1 and has_mary = 1 and has_steve = 0 or
            has_john = 1 and has_mary = 1 and has_steve = 1 or
            has_john = 1 and has_mary = 0 and has_steve = 1 
           )
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

For each row, if the name is either John, Mary or Steve you need to figure out who else is in town to decide if you filter the row away. The most natural way of doing this is with left joins to subquerys. Please notice that this solution works even if there are names other than John, Mary or Steve in the table.

```
WITH cities_with_john AS  (SELECT City, Name FROM cities WHERE Name = 'John'),
     cities_with_Mary AS  (SELECT City, Name FROM cities WHERE Name = 'Mary'),
     cities_with_Steve AS (SELECT City, Name FROM cities WHERE Name = 'Steve')
SELECT c.*
FROM cities c
LEFT JOIN cities_with_John j ON c.City = j.City
LEFT JOIN cities_with_Mary m ON c.City = m.City
LEFT JOIN cities_with_Steve s ON c.City = s.City
WHERE c.Name NOT IN ('John', 'Mary', 'Steve') --Anyone else shows up always
    OR (c.Name = 'Mary' --Mary only shows up if either John or Steve are not in town
        AND (j.Name IS NULL OR s.Name IS NULL))
    OR (c.Name = 'Steve' --Steve only shows up if either Mary or Steve are not in town
        AND (j.Name IS NULL OR m.Name IS NULL))
    OR (c.Name = 'John' --John only shows up if both Mary and Steve are in town, or if both are not
        AND ((s.Name IS NULL AND m.Name IS NULL)
              OR (s.Name IS NOT NULL AND m.Name IS NOT NULL)))
ORDER BY City, Name
```

Please, see the results with this data set, I identified 8 test cases. In each case I also added a fourth name (Kate) for control:

```
City        Name
----------- ------------
Berlin      Kate
Havana      John
Havana      Kate
Havana      Steve
Miami       John
Miami       Kate
Miami       Mary
Miami       Steve
Nairobi     Kate
Nairobi     Mary
New York    John
New York    Kate
New York    Mary
Oslo        John
Oslo        Kate
Paris       Kate
Paris       Mary
Paris       Steve
Tokio       Kate
Tokio       Steve
```

The test cases are:
New York - John and Mary are in the city (should filter out John)
Miami - All of them are in the city (Should filter out Steve and Mary)
Havana - John and Steve are in the city (Should filter out John)
Paris - Mary and Steve are in the city (Should show everyone)
Berlin - None of them are in the city (Should show everyone)
Oslo, Tokio, Nairobi - Only one of them is in the city (Should show everyone)

And this is the result:

```
City         Name
------------ ----------
Berlin       Kate
Havana       Kate
Havana       Steve
Miami        John
Miami        Kate
Nairobi      Kate
Nairobi      Mary
New York     Kate
New York     Mary
Oslo         John
Oslo         Kate
Paris        Kate
Paris        Mary
Paris        Steve
Tokio        Kate
Tokio        Steve
```